# My phone restarts when I connect it to the notebook

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I try to debug android aplication in my phone..

I have already installed Eclipse, I run tests on AVD smoothly and now I want to debug in my phone, but, when I connect it to the notebook for USB port, it restart without allow me to do something.

My phone is a LG Optimus One P500 with openOptimus build 2.202.1, version 2.3.3
My notebook have a ubuntu 13.04, although.. I tried it on windows and occurred the same.

I think that I have change the android version on my phone or make a hard reset, but.. What do you think about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would start by testing another cable

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with your Custom rom. Maybe it wont allow you to connect to a PC or Laptop. Try switching to a different/stable/newer version of the same ROM or revert back to stock rom. If that solves the restart problem make sure you add your device vendor id to the rules file and keep the debugging mode ON.
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
 It should work fine.